# Unexpected behaviour when grouping outliers in pandas [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is in this format

```
df

            Count
DateTime    
2015-01-16  10
2015-01-17  28
2015-01-18  26
2015-01-19  10
2015-01-20  24
2015-01-21  25
```

Im experimenting with this function to eliminate outliers using groupby

```
def replaceit(group):
    mean, std = group.mean(), group.std()
    outliers = (group - mean).abs() > 3*std
    group[outliers] = mean        # or "group[~outliers].mean()"
    return group
```

Creating a copy of that dataframe as I want to use it elsewhere:

```
df2 = df
```

Lets see the output of df2

```
df2

            Count
DateTime    
2015-01-16  10
2015-01-17  28
2015-01-18  26
2015-01-19  10
2015-01-20  24
2015-01-21  25
```

lets use the function

```
df2 = replaceit(df2)

df2 

DateTime
2015-01-16       10.000000
2015-01-17       28.000000
2015-01-18       26.000000
2015-01-19       10.000000
2015-01-20       24.000000
2015-01-21       25.000000
```

BUT now lets see the output of df:

```
df

                Count
DateTime    
2015-01-16  10.000000
2015-01-17  28.000000
2015-01-18  26.000000
2015-01-19  10.000000
2015-01-20  24.000000
2015-01-21  25.000000
```

My question is, why is this happening?
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you need `copy` - `df2 = df.copy()`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that was needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is if use `df2 = df` it is reference to the initial DataFrame. Thus, changing `df2` will change the initial DataFrame `df`.

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df2 = df.copy()
```